# How to check if 2 elements inside an array of objects have the same value, in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

My `users` collection data looks like this inside mongoDB:

```
_id: ObjectId,
sports: [
  {
    name: 'cricket',
    history: [
      {
        from: 10,
        to: 30
      },
      {
        from: 30,
        to: 30
      }
    ]
  },
  // ... other sports as well
]
```

What I'm trying to query for are all the users that have inside `sports.history` an matching element that satisfies this condition: `from === to`. (Users can have multiple sports each with it's own history).
I'm trying to achieve this inside the query, not bring users inside my express app and filter them afterwards.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator, you can go about this using various array operators to query the collection. Consider first flattening the 2D array '$sports.history' with [`$reduce`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/):

```
 {
    $reduce: {
        input: "$sports.history",
        initialValue: [],
        in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
    }
}
```

and filtering the reduced array on the given condition with [`$filter`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

```
{ $filter: {
    input: {
        $reduce: {
            input: "$sports.history",
            initialValue: [],
            in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ]
            }
        }
    },
    cond: {
        $eq: ['$$this.from', '$$this.to']
    }
} }
```

Check the length of the array resulting from the above expression using [`$size`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/):

```
{ $size: { 
    { $filter: {
        input: {
            $reduce: {
                input: '$sports.history',
                initialValue: [],
                in: { $concatArrays: [ '$$value', '$$this' ] }
            }
        },
        cond: {
            $eq: ['$$this.from', '$$this.to']
        }
    } }
} }
```

If length of filtered array is greater than zero, then the user exists:

```
{ $gt: [
    { $size: { 
        $filter: {
            input: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$sports.history",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
                }
            },
            cond: {
                $eq: ['$$this.from', '$$this.to']
            }
        }
    } },
    0
] }
```

Overall your final query should look like this:

```
db.users.find({
    $expr: {
        $gt: [
            { $size: {
                $filter: {
                    input: {
                        $reduce: {
                            input: "$sports.history",
                            initialValue: [],
                            in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
                        }
                    },
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ['$$this.from', '$$this.to']
                    }
                }
            } },
            0
        ]
    }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RF3T6vKmJ39)

Comment: Thank you, it works. For future readers, if you want to see the compressed answer, press the Mongo Playground link in the answer above.